# What is the integral of $\coth(\sqrt{\tan(x)+1}*\cos(x\sin(x)))$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I don't know where to start. Trying to take a Taylor series, the first derivative is:$$\frac{d}{dx}(\coth(\sqrt{\tan(x) + 1}\cos(x\sin(x)))) = \frac{\sec^2(x)\cos(x\sin(x))}{(2\sqrt{\tan(x) + 1}}-\sin(x \sin(x))\sqrt{\tan(x) + 1}(\sin(x)+x\cos(x)))(-csch^2(\sqrt{\tan(x) + 1}\cos(x\sin(x))))$$Which is very complicated, so there is no use trying to get a Taylor Series. Please help!

Comment: Your function comes from a special imagination.

Comment: I was actually playing around on Desmos.

Comment: I give +1 for masochism. :)

Comment: Thanks for noticing that @AlannRosas.

Comment: My first question absolutely has to be "Why are you doing this?" and my second is "How could you look at this an even suspect it can be integrated?"

Comment: If you are trying to do a series, then try putting each multiplier, for example a•b•c, into a series or do each argument as a series, such as a(y)*b(z)*c(x), with different indices to avoid cauchy products. You may end up with an ugly multi sum representation, if this is even possible, but at least you will have an integral. Maybe.

Answer (score 3):

*The limit of your imagination seems to very very close to $\infty$ (which is not bad).*

Considering the *monster*
$$f(x)=\coth(\cos(x\sin(x))\sqrt{\tan(x)+1})$$ it has vertical asymptotes at $x=-\frac \pi 4$ and $x=\frac \pi 2$. However, the function
$$g(x)=\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-x\right) \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)f(x)$$ is not so bad and does not any discontinuity or asymptote.

So, suppose that you find a good polynomial which fits $g(x)$, that is to say
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^p a_n \,x^n$$ which makes that
$$\int f(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^p a_n\int\frac{x^n}{ \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-x\right)}\,dx$$ Each ot these integrals
$$I_n=\int\frac{x^n}{ \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-x\right)}\,dx$$ is simple since
$$\frac{3 \pi  n }{4}I_n=\frac{2 x^{n+1}}{\pi -2
   x} \, _2F_1\left(1,1;1-n;\frac{\pi }{\pi -2 x}\right)+$$ $$\left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^n \, _2F_1\left(-n,-n;1-n;\frac{\pi }{4 x+\pi }\right)$$

Now, **my question** : are you sure that you will not prefer numerical integration ?

Comment: You have coth(cos(xsin(x)*$\sqrt{\mathrm{tan(x)+1}}))$ when the question asks for $\mathrm{coth(cos\big(xsin(x)\big)*\sqrt{\mathrm{tan(x)+1}})}$, but interesting approach.

Comment: I agree with @TymaGaidash, but I'm amazed at your approach because I haven't seen it before!

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Just a typo ! All the remaining is unchanged.